# SQLiteOutOfMemoryException, inserting 97k data into a SQLITE database on android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, memory

I created a SQLITE bank for my application, when I try to insert one of the bases that contains 97 thousand lines it gives the error failed to allocate 120000 bytes of memory and then Out Of Memory, could someone help me how I can do it to be able to insert a large amount of data in a table of a SQLite database on android.

this is the function of my repository that I'm using to insert the data:

```
        public long InsertWeb(AreaEmp item) {

        long retorn = 0;

        try {



          ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put("_id", item.get_id());
            contentValues.put("no_divisao_1", item.getNo_divisao_1());
            contentValues.put("no_divisao_2", item.getNo_divisao_2());
            contentValues.put("no_divisao_3", item.getNo_divisao_3());
            contentValues.put("no_divisao_4", item.getNo_divisao_4());
            contentValues.put("ds_divisao_1", item.getDs_divisao_1());
            contentValues.put("ds_divisao_2", item.getDs_divisao_2());
            contentValues.put("ds_divisao_3", item.getDs_divisao_3());
            contentValues.put("ds_divisao_4", item.getDs_divisao_4());
            contentValues.put("cd_subregiao", item.getCd_subregiao());
            contentValues.put("dt_plantio", item.getDt_plantio());
            contentValues.put("id_empresa", item.getId_empresa());
            contentValues.put("id_talhao", item.getId_talhao());
            contentValues.put("id_tipo_uso", item.getId_tipo_uso());
            contentValues.put("id_versao", item.getId_versao());
            contentValues.put("no_municipio", item.getNo_municipio());
            contentValues.put("no_ordem", item.getNo_ordem());
            contentValues.put("nu_bloco", item.getNu_bloco());
            contentValues.put("vl_area", item.getVl_area());
            contentValues.put("vl_espac_linha", item.getVl_espac_linha());
            contentValues.put("vl_espac_planta", item.getVl_espac_planta());

            resultInsert = sqLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(table, null, contentValues);
            contentValues.clear();
            //sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();


        } finally {
            if (sqLiteDatabase != null && sqLiteDatabase.inTransaction()) {
                sqLiteDatabase.endTransaction();
            }
        }
        return  resultInsert;
    }
```

and this is the function that calls in main to insert all the items in the list:

```
     for (AreaEmp item : list){

                    new AreaEmpRepositorio(context).InsertWeb(item);





                }
```

Comment: What exactly is 97 thousand?

Comment: is 97k list data to insert into sqlite database

Comment: `AreaEmpRepositorio repo = new AreaEmpRepositorio(context);` You could create the repository before the loop, which is faster. On the alternatives: await the answers.